# JSON XML Graph Data

Tags: python

I am working on a Python script that will extract data from Database and prepare data for a front graph amCharts tool. I am returning data via an AJAX call made from the front end side in JSON / XML format.

Is it safe to return data in JSON / XML format to browser - in case if my tool goes to live wouldn’t the JSON / XML format would be viewable to client side before reading. Is it a safe way for data to be transmitted to client side?

What are the other ways the Python script can print out data such that client side can show data in graphs etc in secured way? Also is my approach correct - is there any other way to represent data as Graphs?

Please advice

Comment: Please explain what the specific security concern is.  That the user can see the graph data?  That a network sniffer would see the graph data?

Comment: The data is sensitive which would contain about the user confidential information. The data returned back will have a pattern of sets of rows which we do not want other than the user to view it. What are the ways apart from using JSON / XML that I can use safely send to client side and be decrypted to be represented as a graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use HTTPS on your server, so that the data is encrypted as it leaves the server.

Ultimately, though, the browser will decrypt the data. If at anytime you don't even want the target end-user to see the data, then you have to follow this rule: don't send it.